# Crystal Report dataset login issue

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my crystal report I have a dataset set as a source, but I don't have any credentials set there and my app is throwing this as a problem...

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: can you post your code to generate your edition?

Comment: I don't have anything related to the login in my code since I am using dataset... In the designer of the dataset I set only source a psychical file which I made in visual studio. @romulus001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code is missing :

```
MyRPTDocument.DataSourceConnections.Item[0].IntegratedSecurity = True;
MyRPTDocument.DataSourceConnections.Item[0].SetConnexion("server name", "database name", "", "");
```